# Type Error in Controller no implicit conversion of Symbol into String Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

The params in my controller seem to be a Hash when I expect them to be params.

Here are the parameters on the error page

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"1SmzXJdbOsAjHo2z+j0vPjnh6uSWX8Mmwb9LAnrtjNo=",
 "hour_log"=>{"assignment"=>"Tutoring",
 "hours"=>"2",
 "supervisor"=>"GW Library",
 "date"=>"8/10/15"},
 "commit"=>"Create"}
```

Here is the controller:

```
class HoursController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_user
  def new
    @entry = HourLog.all
    @hour = HourLog.new
  end
  def create
    @hour = HourLog.new(log_params)
  end
  private
  def log_params
    require(:HourLog).permit(:assignment, :hours, :supervisor, :date )
  end
end
```

Here's the view:

```
<%= form_for(@hour, url: log_path) do |f|%>
              <tr>
                <td id="dashfield"><%=f.text_field :assignment, :placeholder=> "Assignment"%></td>
                <td id="dashfiled"><%=f.text_field :hours, :placeholder => "Hours"%></td>
                <td id="dashfield"><%=f.text_field :supervisor, :placeholder=> "Supervisor/Location"%></td>
                <td id="dashfield"><%=f.text_field :date, :placeholder=> "Date"%></td>
                <td id="dashbtn"><%=f.submit 'Create' %></td>
              </tr>
          <%end%>
```

Here are the routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'users#index'
  get '/signup' => 'users#new'
  resources :users
  get '/login' => 'sessions#new'
  post '/login' => 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
  get '/dashboard' => 'hours#new'
  post '/dashboard' => 'hours#create', as: :log
end
```

I'm using Rails 4.1. Thanks for the help!

Comment: show us the full error stack..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you have to write the strong parameter method as follows :

```
def log_params
  params.require(:hour_log).permit(:assignment, :hours, :supervisor, :date )
end
```

Comment: I feel pretty dumb right now, i had it in my other controller and didn't even notice. Thanks!